# date difference and match with value in javascript

Tags: date, duration

Hi I have the Drop down with values as "One year ", "Two year",...etc.. Ok? also i have two ajax textbox with calender extender . I want to popup alert message if dropdown selected value is "One year" and duration between the both textbox value Means dates not matches. getting what i mean ? please help me.
How can i get this scenario in javascript ??

Answer (score 0):

```
Algorithm :
1.Get the both date from the text box.
2. The find the epcoch time for each date. //
3. subtract the both dates.
4. subtract_result = 365*24*60*60  // Finding the 1 year timestamp values
5. So, it the difference exceed than above calculation , you could sure that the date is mis matching.
```

`Javascript:
    // This is for first date
    first = new Date(2010, 03, 08, 15, 30, 10); // Get the first date epoch object
    document.write((first.getTime())/1000); // get the actual epoch values
    second = new Date(2012, 03, 08, 15, 30, 10); // Get the first date epoch object
    document.write((second.getTime())/1000); // get the actual epoch values
    diff= second - first ;
    one_day_epoch = 24*60*60 ;  // calculating one epoch
    if ( diff/ one_day_epoch > 365 ) // check , is it exceei
    {
    alert( 'date is exceeding one year');
    }`